# Find out of there is a HorizontalScrollView inside a view

Tags: android, android-layout

Trying to figure out if any view in a ViewGroup is a HorizontalScrollView, for some reason this code doesn't work to well. If someone could help me see what I'm doing wrong then I'd appreciate it.

I'm sure there's a horizontal scroll view in my layout and that it's a child of the ViewGroup that I'm passing in.

```
private boolean isAnyViewHorizontallyScrollable(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    for (int i=0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if (viewGroup.getChildAt(i) instanceof HorizontalScrollView) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Found a horizontal scroll view");
            return true;
        } else if (viewGroup.getChildAt(i) instanceof ViewGroup) {
            isAnyViewHorizontallyScrollable((ViewGroup)viewGroup.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You recursively call your method, but you don't do anything with these results...
Try returning true when you find a nested HorizontalScrollView, like this:

```
else if (viewGroup.getChildAt(i) instanceof ViewGroup &&
         isAnyViewHorizontallyScrollable((ViewGroup)viewGroup.getChildAt(i)))
    return true;
}
```

Comment: No trouble. Consider the name `containsHorizontalScrollView()`, it is a little more descriptive and sounds better (to me at least).